# NavigationStateUtils not pushing (using NavigationExperimental)

Tags: react-native

Here's my AppState class:

```
export default class AppState {
    constructor() {
        this.navigationState = {
            index: 0,
            routes: [{ key: "InitialView" }]
        };
    }
    updateNavigationState(type, route = null) {
        switch (type) {
            case NavigationStateUpdateType.Push:
                console.log(this.navigationState.routes.length);
                console.log(this.navigationState.routes[0].key);
                if (route !== null) {
                    console.log("Route: " + route);
                    this.navigationState = NavigationStateUtils.push(this.navigationState, { key: route });
                }
            case NavigationStateUpdateType.Pop:
                this.navigationState = NavigationStateUtils.pop(this.navigationState);
        }
    }
}
```

Now if I do this inside `InitialView`:

```
this.props.appState.updateNavigationState(NavigationStateUpdateType.Push, "InitialView1");
```

Nothing happens. It seems like `NavigationStateUtil.push`doesn't work. Here's what the Console looks like:

```
AppState.js:18 1
AppState.js:19 InitialView
AppState.js:21 Route: InitialView1
AppState.js:18 1
AppState.js:19 InitialView
AppState.js:21 Route: InitialView1
AppState.js:18 1
AppState.js:19 InitialView
AppState.js:21 Route: InitialView1
```

Why isn't `routes` being updated? Or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT

My `GlobalNavigation` component (as asked):

```
const { CardStack: NavigationCardStack } = NavigationExperimental;
let GlobalNavigation = class GlobalNavigation extends Component {
    render() {
        return (React.createElement(NavigationCardStack, {renderScene: this._renderScene.bind(this), navigationState: this.props.appState.navigationState}));
    }
    _renderScene() {
        return (React.createElement(InitialView, {appState: this.props.appState}));
    }
};
```

By the way: all this code is generated by TypeSript.

Comment: Can you show more of your code? For instance, if you have a renderScene method and also the CardStack you are using?

Comment: @NaderDabit done.